# Large movement in vieos causes red and green shadows[moved from computer graphics]

Tags: video, graphics-card, amd-radeon

When I'm playing videos, in some videos, when a large amount of movement happens, a green and red copy of whatever moved appears. Also when I press play, a green glitch appears at the bottom of the screen. I'm not sure if this belongs here, but I couldn't find anywhere else to put it. There is probably an answer somewhere else on Stack Exchange, but I don't know how to phrase it in a search term.

I'm using an AMD Radeon R9 290X, any help would be appreciated

Comment: Have you installed the graphics drivers? By the way, when you post this type of questions you should say whether the drivers have been installed and the operating system you're using, version, build, etc.

Comment: Aha I figured it out, I updated and now it works, but for whatever reason amd wants me to downgrade back to the version I had before. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens when GPU is overloaded. What to do:

- Make sure the graphic drivers are installed and updated;
- Decrease the fps of the video file that is played;
- Decrease the resolution of the video file that is played;
- Make sure the video file is not rescaled runtime while is played.